# Will Gzip compression affect my db queries?

Tags: gzip, client-side

Maybe it is a stupid question, but will gzip compression affect my db queries ( i mean, will they be cached) or gzip is related only to html and css output delivered to browser and php stuff will still be efecuted on the server with every page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using HTTP server compression then as you guessed its a way to optimize transmission from server to client, it (generally) works transparently.

Browser extensions as firebug or monitor tools such as fiddler can help you see whats is really happens behind the scenes.